# select does not use index when using different column

Tags: mariadb

For my server:

```
> select version();
+---------------------+
| version()           |
+---------------------+
| 10.0.17-MariaDB-log |
+---------------------+
```

I created a small workable example of the problem I'm facing.
For a table of 3'322'865 records, a simple `SELECT` uses an index when one field is used, but not when it's the other one used.

```
> show create table temp;
 temp  | CREATE TABLE `temp` (
  `ep` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `r_a` decimal(15,2) DEFAULT NULL,
  KEY `ep_idx` (`ep`),
  KEY `r_a_idx` (`r_a`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=latin1
```

so, both fields are indexed.

When `r_a` is used for retrieval, an index is used by MariaDB:

```
> explain select r_a from temp where r_a > 1000;                                                        
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type  | possible_keys | key     | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra                    |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | temp  | range | r_a_idx       | r_a_idx | 8       | NULL | 1657760 | Using where; Using index |
+------+-------------+-------+-------+---------------+---------+---------+------+---------+--------------------------+
```

The `rows` count seem very large.  Any ideas on how to improve this?  Analyze the table?

But a full scan is performed when field `ep` is used instead of `r_a`.

```
> explain select ep from temp where r_a > 1000;
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
| id   | select_type | table | type | possible_keys | key  | key_len | ref  | rows    | Extra       |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
|    1 | SIMPLE      | temp  | ALL  | r_a_idx       | NULL | NULL    | NULL | 3315520 | Using where |
+------+-------------+-------+------+---------------+------+---------+------+---------+-------------+
```

Why does this happen?  How to force or make MariaDB to use an index when the latter statement is used?

Comment: Why do you want to force use of the index? For some reason, the optimizer decided it was better to use the table and not the index. Do you think it will be more efficient?

Comment: With no index, it scans more than three million rows.  Not bad in this simple query, but it makes a big difference when this problem happens on a multiple join query, which is my case.  And it's strange to me that the optimizer changed it's algorithm of search when the `where` clause is the same.  AFAICT, the fields retrieved by `select` do not impact significantly the speed of execution of the query.

Comment: I see no join in the code. How many rows pass the condition (`r_a > 1000`)? The columns selected do impact significantly the way the query is executed (but maybe not the speed). When you select the `ep` column, if the index is used, the execution would have to be: "use the index to find all the rows that have r_a>1000, then go to the table and retrieve from these rows the `ep` values."

Comment: I simplified and narrowed the problem to this, that's why I showed no `join`.

Comment: 1123511 rows show up when `r_a > 1000`.

Comment: So, the optimizer decided it was cheaper to read 3 million rows (and test which rows to skip) than read 1 million rows from the index and then go to the table and read the related 1 million rows. That would probably be much less efficient because the rows would probably be interleaved in the table, and the entire table might be read again anyway.

Comment: You can try adding an index on `(r_a, ep)` and see that it will be used instead - and the table will not be used.

Comment: The index you suggested (r_a, ep) returns an `EXPLAIN` similar to the one I posted above for `SELECT r_a ...`, so it uses an `index` now.  But, so many rows 1657760 it has to scan?

Comment: All of them. You want all the data returned, so what else could it be?

Comment: I don't know the internals, but 1657760 is 47.5% more of rows than those that are returned.

Comment: Ah, yeah, that's an estimate. It will scan the 1123511 rows returned. It will start from the first value (say 1001.23) and read all the index to the end.

Comment: Maybe you want to place an answer for me to accept it.  One other thing :-)  what's the logic behind the index with two columns?